# Optimize a repeated squaring algorithmn

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I wrote a python code to raise a 2 by 2 matrix by the power of n using the algorithmn technique of repeated squaring, but on inputs where n is above 300k the computation time exceeds 10s(the max amount of time my algorithm should take)

Is there a way to optimize my code?

```
def multiply_mat(X,Y):
 result = [[0,0],
      [0,0]]
 result[0][0] = (Y[0][0] * X[0][0]) + (Y[0][1] * X[1][0]) 
 result[0][1] = (Y[0][0] * X[0][1]) + (Y[0][1] * X[1][1]) 
 result[1][0] = (Y[1][0] * X[0][0]) + (Y[1][1] * X[1][0]) 
 result[1][1] = (Y[0][1] * X[1][0]) + (Y[1][1] * X[1][1])
 return result

def power_mat(M, n):
 if n == 0:
    return 1
 elif n == 1:
    return M
 elif n % 2 == 1:
     return multiply_mat(M,power_mat(multiply_mat(M,M), (n-1)/2))
 else:
    return power_mat(multiply_mat(M,M), n/2)
```

Comment: If you expect `n` to go above 300k, looking to see if you can diagonalize the matrix might be worth your while.

Comment: @Kraigolas can it be done with the built-in python libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kraigolas noted, you should diagonalize your matrix first if possible. To do so, use `numpy.linalg.eig()`, and the calculation becomes very fast:

```py
def power_mat(M, n):
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(M)
    return v @ np.diag(np.power(w, n)) @ np.linalg.inv(v)
```

In terms of speed, this is roughly independent of `n`. About half the time is spent doing the diagonalization.

For a 2x2 matrix, `power_mat()` takes about 40µs on my machine.